# How can I know which childview is shown on the current Device screen in a scrollview?

Tags: android, view, scroll

How can I know which childview is shown on the current device screen, in a scrollview?

I want to make an infinite Ruler App, so I need to dynamically add and remove view when the view is flipping, but how and where can I find out which childview is shown on the current device screen, so I can add or remove the correct view when I get that childview changed notify?

Or, can anyone who can give me some other idea to realize this function?

Answer (score 1):

I have met this problem too. you can call getlocalonscreen function to get coordinate of view. for example:

1.

```
view.getlocaloncreen(xy);// xy[0] is x axis, xy[1] is y axis.
```

2.

```
int nScreenWid = getwindowsmanager().getdefaultdisplay().getwidth();
int nScreenHei = getwindowsmanager().getdefaultdisplay().getHeight();
```

3.

```
if( xy[0] > nscreenWid )
{
  // your view is beyond the x axis.
}
if( xy[1] > xxxxhei )
{ // beyond y axis }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollView.getScrollY()` to find how far down the scroll view the scroll point is, and compare that to the heights of the child views (adding them up as you go along) to see which one must be on screen.

Comment: thanks
getScrollY() maybe right.
I just found anyview have scrollTo() function,so now i immediately use lineanerlayout instead ScrollView